# Attaching multiple images using adb

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I need to attach two pictures via adb command

As I understood, I need to use the action - android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE

But I can't make a command since there is no documentation on this

I can't do it through an extra stream, because only one file link is specified in the value of this parameter

Example of command with one picture:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t  image/* --eu android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/file.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify multiple files by multiple ` --eu ...` parameters?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Only one was attached

Comment: Could be a problem of the app you target via `am start`. Extract the APK file and decompile the code (e.g. using Jadx) to see if the app supports multiple attachments at all.

Comment: No, that's not the point. I don't specify the application. When the command is executed, a pop-up window appears with the application selection. Application 100% supports attaching multiple pictures.
If you perform the file attachment action manually, logs via the command - ```adb shell "logcat | grep intent"``` show a brief description of the adb command used:
```{{ace=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE type=image/* flag=0x80001 cmp=com.package clip={image/* U:content://media/external/images/media ...} (has extras)}```
I don't understand there is what is a ``clip`` and how can I do it

Comment: If you specify the app/intent in `am start` or use application chooser doesn't matter, in the end the command is sent to exactly one app. And that app has to support multiple attachments via Intent. That the app allows multiple attachments via app UI doesn't matter, the code path is different. You have to check the activity that is called by `android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE` and check it's code if it processes multiple attachments.

Comment: There is way to do it via java android. ```Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");```
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents
But i also can't get the command